# Facebook on WebView looks weird

Tags: android, webview

My WebView code:

```
WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
                {

                 return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }
            };

            webV = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

            webV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
            webV.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
            webV.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webV.setSaveEnabled(true);

            webV.loadUrl("http://"+value);
```

But Facebook looks weird on it and nothing like Facebook in web mode like in chrome, it looks like this:
[image]

And I wish it would look like regular web Facebook.

Comment: Wierd looks weird! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's serving up the mobile optimised version of the site. It might be possible to get round this by changing the `WebView`'s user agent like this;

```
String desktopUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
webV.getSettings().setUserAgent(desktopUserAgent);
```

Make sure you do this before trying to load the page.